# JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY not working with nested objects (Jackson)

Tags: java, spring, jackson, lombok, mapstruct

I am having some problems when using Jackson Access.READ_ONLY on a DTO inside another DTO.

[AuthorDTO.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hxfz.png)

AuthorDTO is the RequestBody on AuthorController post/put methods and it is also the ResponseEntity object. What I want is only show BookDTO on the response, as I am doing with other AuthorDTO properties such as Author.creationDate, but it seems it does not work with BookDTO

Nothing I have tried so far seems to work, as AuthoDTO.BookDTO property is still part of the request, as you can see on this swagger capture:

[Swagger UI RequestBody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgpSr.png)

Any help is welcome

PS: I am using Lombok and Mapstruct

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
private BookDTO book;
```

If you want to hide something from Swagger you can use @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true).

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem, I had the same problem.

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
@Schema(allOf = BookDTO.class)
private BookDTO book;
```